# Cannot use import statement outside a module when I import a module

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am trying to use [vue-loadmore-simple](https://github.com/tanagang/vue-loadmore-simple) in my nuxt.js project.

I created `plugins/vue-loadmore-simple.js` to let Vue use it.

```
// if I commented the 3 lines, it will works again.
import Vue from 'vue'
import LoadMore from 'vue-loadmore-simple'
Vue.use(LoadMore)
```

and in `nuxt.config.js` plugins, I added it:

```js
"@/plugins/vue-loadmore-simple.js"
```

but however when I `npm run dev`, there I get error:

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it with a new project, it does totally work for me.
You will need to give us a [repro] or at least, more details code-wise.

---

Meanwhile, I'll recommend using maybe more battle-tested from a well known developer.
Like [vue-mugen-scroll](https://github.com/egoist/vue-mugen-scroll), I've worked it by the past and it's doing the job well.
On top of being written in english and being more popular.

This is a [vue project](https://github.com/kissu/pet-friends) where I used it, should totally work with Nuxt too.